# How to put gridlayout in a certain spot on the frame?

Tags: java, function, methods, view, frame

Right now I have my view's layout set to null and I just place the button and text field with specific coordinates. I also need to have a grid on there and I'm wondering how to put it in a certain spot on my frame? All of the examples I have found online and in my book just use gridlayout as the main setLayout which I don't want

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use appropriate layouts where ever possible.  Make use of compound layouts to produce more complex visuals

Comment: You can nest JPanels in JPanels in JPanels, each one having a different layout manager.  Go crazy.

Comment: okay thanks that is clear. What i want to do though is set the grid layout to whatever specifications the user gives me. I am wondering how to set it and then change it once I get the number they want?